# Regular expression to get facebook profile

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to check matches facebook url and get profile in one regular expression:
I have:

> http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123456789 
>   https://facebook.com/someusername

I need:

```
123456789
someusername
```

using this regular expression:

```
(?<=(https?://(www.)?facebook.com/(profile.php?id=)?))([^/#?]+)
```

I get:

```
profile.php
someusername
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: ok, maybe you can provide some more information about your goal? maybe  there are more simple methods without regexs?

Comment: http://rubular.com says "Fix forward slashes" and "Invalid pattern in look-behind". Use it interactively to get to a good regex.

Comment: Good question, showed effort, tried something, first day @ stackoverflow +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with others on using System.Uri but your regex needs two modifications to work:

- \ in (profile.php\?id=)
- (\n|$) at the end

  (?<=(https?://(www\.)?facebook\.com/(profile\.php\?id=)?))([^/#?]+)(\n|$)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is great resolving of the problem!

Comment: You should escape your dots \.

Answer (score 8):

I advise you to use the [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class to get this information. It does the difficult work for you and can handle all sorts of edge cases.

```
var profileUri = new Uri(@"http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123456789");
var usernameUri = new Uri(@"https://facebook.com/someusername");

Console.Out.WriteLine(profileUri.Query); // prints "?id=123456789"
Console.Out.WriteLine(usernameUri.AbsolutePath); // prints "/someusername"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
https?://(?:www.)?facebook.com/(?:profile.php\?id=)?(.+)
```

or

```
https?://(?:www.)?facebook.com/(?:profile.php\?id=)?([^/#\?]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example writes the query `?id=123456789` to the console.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri ("http://www.facebook.com/");
Uri myUri = new Uri (baseUri, "/profile.php?id=123456789");

Console.WriteLine(myUri.Query);
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: A facebook url is an example, I need to get profile from other sites too and if the url may be: http:Site.com/PROFILE/someElse to get the profile you need to write another method, this is not good practice

Comment: This is just an example, the Query property contains any query information included in the URI!